# href mailto not working on firefox

Tags: jquery, html

**Firefox Issue:-**
I am trying to do this:

```js
 $("#contact_us_link").on('click', function() {
      $("#loading").hide();
      var contact_us_mail = "<?php echo "mailto:" . get_support_email_super_admin(); ?>";
      window.open(contact_us_mail);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="contact_us_link" class="hand-pointer" style="color:rgb(0, 128, 194)">
```

when I click, It opens only new tab, nothing else happens.
Any solution?

**UPDATE:**
Hi vard, jquery href not works **FOR LOADING IMAGE HIDE** :

```
$("#contact_us_link").on('click', function() {
        $("#loading").hide();
        var contact_us_mail = "<?php echo "mailto:" . get_contact_us_email(); ?>";
        window.location.href=contact_us_mail;
         $("#loading").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Do you have PHP running and properly configured?  Is your HTML in a PHP document or running on a server that can recognize PHP in HTML?

Comment: What do you see when you debug the js in your browser's inspector tool?

Comment: Whats wrong with code? , it works fine in IE, and chrome.
Problem with Firefox.

Comment: Just change "mailto" to 'mailto'. Change the quotation and check

Comment: @user2584538 If he do that he will have a syntax error...

Comment: What is your current setting for mailto in firefox? (in the application settings tab) And btw why don't you use a simple `<a href="mailto:..">` ?

Comment: See, In our web app, while loading every page loading image appears, so, there is issue with loading image, so we are opening it into new tab using JQUERY. when we use href of anchor, loading image in our app keeps continue.

Comment: @vard: firefox setting for mailto is use windows live mail (default).

Comment: @SujVan And when you're using Chrome, or IE, is it WLM too that is being launched when clicking on the mailto?

Comment: YES. its opening  WLM.

Comment: And for this loading image story, you can do this in the other way: keep the mailto in the `<a>` tag and just hide the loading image on click on this link. If you don't use `e.preventDefault()` you're fine.

Comment: Could you try with `location.href` instead of `window.open`?

Comment: Hi vard, jquery href not works hiding loading image, post updated. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I am not so sure about mixing PHP code with JS. Never tried that, never seen that.

How about doing it this way?

```
$("#contact_us_link").on('click', function() {
    $("#loading").hide();
    var contact_us_mail = "mailto:"+email_address;
    window.open(contact_us_mail);
});
```

If the email is returned by a PHP function, maybe you can use an AJAX call to fetch it.